# Markdown: Processing order for registred Pattern

Tags: python, markdown

I have written a python extension for markdown based on `InlineProcessor` who correctly match when the pattern appears:

**Custom extension:**

```py
from markdown.util import AtomicString, etree
from markdown.extensions import Extension
from markdown.inlinepatterns import InlineProcessor

RE = r'(#)(\S{3,})'

class MyPattern(InlineProcessor):
    def handleMatch(self, m, data):
        tag = m.group(2)

        el = etree.Element("a")
        el.set('href', f'/{tag}')
        el.text = AtomicString(f'#{tag}')

        return el, m.start(0), m.end(0)

class MyExtension(Extension):
    def extendMarkdown(self, md, md_globals):
        # If processed by attr_list extension, not by this one
        md.inlinePatterns.register(MyPattern(RE, md), 'my_tag', 200)

def makeExtension(*args, **kwargs):
    return MyExtension(*args, **kwargs)
```

**IN:** `markdown('foo #bar')`

**OUT:** `<p>foo <a href="/bar">#bar</a></p>`

But my extension is breaking a native feature called [attr_list](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/attr_list/) in extra of python markdown.

**IN:** `### Title {style="color:#FF0000;"}`

**OUT:** `<h3>Title {style="color:<a href="/FF0000;&quot;}">#FF0000;"}</a></h3>`

I'm not sure to correctly understand how [Python-Markdown](https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown) register / apply patterns on the text. I try to register my pattern with a high number to put it at the end of the process `md.inlinePatterns.register(MyPattern(RE, md), 'my_tag', 200)` but it doesn't do the job.

I have look at the [source code of attr_list extension](https://github.com/Python-Markdown/markdown/blob/master/markdown/extensions/attr_list.py) and they use `Treeprocessor` based class. Did I need to have a class-based on`Treeprocessor` and not an `InlineProcessor` for my **MyPattern**? To find a way to don't apply my tag on element how already have matched with another one (there: `attr_list`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a stricter regular expression which won't result in false matches. Or perhaps you need to alter the syntax you use so that it doesn't clash with other legitimate text.

First of all, the order of events is correct. Using your example input:

```
### Title {style="color:#FF0000;"}
```

When the `InlineProcessor` gets it, so far it has been processed to this:

```
<h3>Title {style="color:#FF0000;"}</h3>
```

Notice that the block level tags are now present (`<h3>`), but the `attr_list` has not been processed. And that is your problem. Your regular expression is matching `#FF0000;"}` and converting that to a link: `<a href="/FF0000;&quot;}">#FF0000;"}</a>`.

Finally, after all InlinePrecessors are done, the `attr_list` TreeProsessor is run, but with the link in the middle, it doesn't recognize the text as a valid attr_list and ignores it (as it should).

In other words, your problem has nothing to do with order at all. You can't run an inline processor after the attr_list TreeProcessor, so you need to explore other alternatives. You have at least two options:

1. Rewrite your regular expression to not have false matches. You might want to try using word boundaries or something.
2. Reconsider your proposed new syntax. `#bar` is a pretty indistinct syntax which is likely to reoccur elsewhere in the text and result in false matches. Perhaps you could require it to be wrapped in brackets or use some character other than a hash.

Personally, I would strongly suggest the second option. Read some text with `#bar` in it, it would not be obvious tome that that is a link. However, `[#bar]` (or similar) would be much more clear.

Comment: That exactly the two solutions what I was considering. `Treeprocessor` is applied after all the `InlineProcessor` substitution and my tag change the syntax, who break parsing. By looking at the [document of etree](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) we see it applied on `root`, who is my `html` code. I consider replacing the colors in hex to RGB but that will only postpone the problem until later. I will follow your advice and improve my syntax!